# GParted not able to dd Unallocted space to /dev/sda*

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-esxi, gparted

There is no way I can extend the current volume with the new allocated space that is available, and the locks can't be opened.

[image]

Edit: after de-activating it, it was possible to expand it. And I actived again, but the new 1GB was not added.

[image]

Fdisk shows:

```
root@youbuntu:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   999423   997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 16777215 15775746  7.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 16775167 15773696  7.5G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 5.5 GiB, 5926551552 bytes, 11575296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 1020 MiB, 1069547520 bytes, 2088960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

There is 5.5GB space instead of 7.5.

Comment: The operation was clearly successful.

Comment: No, the new added 1GB is not available yet @MichaelHampton

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all of the space is there.  Looks like you haven't extended your filesystem

```
resize2fs /dev/sda5
e2fsck /dev/sda5
```

Comment: de-activated and activated it, but no results. added the startpost.

Comment: $ resize2fs /dev/sda5
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda5
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

Comment: unmount the device.   all of this has to be done with the location unmounted

Comment: had to do this: lvextend -r -l +100%free /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root :) thnx

Answer (score 0):

Find Root disk: `$ df -h`

Run `$ lvextend -r -l +100%free /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`